# How to find and kill all the decendent process in Go?

Tags: go

I am looking for a cross platform (various flavours of Unix, including Linux) to find and kill all processes spawned by my program. For Linux, I can walk to /proc to obtain this information, and I am sure I can find somethinf similar for OS X and *BSD. But I'd prefer if there were a standard library for this.

Background: I am writing a custom job schedular which needs to terminate the jobs that don't complete within a given period of time. Simply killing (SIGTERM, followed by SIGKILL- if the formar is not ignored) the child process works fine when the job doesn't spawn any other process or handles SIGTERM properly and takes care of the cleanup. But I don't control the jobs - and I know at least some that are poorly written. In the latter case, the system is left with a bunch of orphaned process which keep holdin on to certain resouces and cause all sorts of problems.

Any pointer to libraries or some cross platform way of doing this would be welcome.

Comment: Normally you kill the process group: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32921792/killing-processes-on-timeout-in-go-code?

Comment: Thanks for the pointer!